# [DataGridClass]: How to make second column of the resultset a hyperlink?

Tags: php, html

I am using following class to show a grid like appearance with pagination on my home page. The class is very good and is working fine.

When the grid shows records, I just want to make the second column values as a hyperlink. I tried adding a href ... in the class where $c is updating, but it is not working. Can anyone help me out.

This class also uses "style.css" file that is also available from the link below. Are any changes needed there?

http://www.webmastergate.com/php/paginate-query-results.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function getRows(), near the very last lines of the function where the $c variable is set. You have to somehow test whether this is the column you want to add the link. Suggest that you set up another associative array which store a key and a callback function

```
   $r = '';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $c = '';

        foreach($row as $key=>$field) {
                //manipulate data here
            $c .= $this->fmtField($key, $field);
        }
        $r .= sprintf($this->rowfmt, $cr ? $classodd : $classeven, $c);
        $cr = 1 - $cr;
    }
```

Another datagrid I will recommend is http://www.eyesis.ca/projects/datagrid.html - it partly removes the need to add in link as you can add custom actions to each row.

Comment: Thanks for that alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You can delegate the responsibility to the formatting to the mysql query for a possible workaround.

for example you can format the query like this one:

```
SELECT firstField, 
    concat ('<a href="', secondField, '">', thirdField,'</a>') as link_column, 
    ....
```

assuming that in the second field you have the URL and in the third one you saved the text of the link.

Another solution (no text) can be

```
SELECT firstField, 
    concat ('<a href="', secondField, '">', secondField,'</a>') as link_column,
    ....
```

If you need to show the URL other than make the link.

I've perused the class and think there aren't other solution without modifying it because you can't address a single column in a row.